# Advertising only certain vendors, rather than allowing AdSense to decide?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

I'm brainstorming a site that keeps a catalog of certain vendors. If a given vendor is sufficiently verified, **I want to specifically advertise *that* vendor only** in a block dedicated to that purpose. (Either they could supply the ad graphic, or we'd produce it for them, as a value-added service.)

Likely a number of "select" vendors might share that block, or else I could simply dedicate the block to say, one select vendor per week. Whichever is easier for now.

The site will also have standard ads targeted to the market in question, via AdSense. These will however appear only in separate blocks / spaces used for general advertising.

I have no clue how to go about advertising these select vendors. Is it technically possible through AdSense, or how would I otherwise go about this? Consider me new to all this.

EDIT: Is [Revive AdServer](https://www.revive-adserver.com/) a better choice for this, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Ad Server.   Feel free to use any that suits your needs, but Google has one and makes it available for free: [DFP](https://www.google.com/dfp).

It is a good choice for you if you are running AdSense. It has tighter integration with AdSense than other ad servers.